# max-width changes its value automatically

Tags: html, css, width

I have a question about `max-width` and why does it change itself Dependeds on display width.

here is my code:

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

So the `max-width` is 500px but when I resize my display size, `max-width` value changes.

In the image below I have a result size with 150px width:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJKqt.png)

as you can see my division width is actually 150px, not 500px which was my `max-width` value.

So why does `max-width` automatically changed its value? Is it correct to say if the display width is smaller than `max-width`, then it matches the width of screen?

Cheers

Comment: We can't see absolute widths from an image. Please make your code into a runnable snippet and describe what we have to do to see the phenomenon. And could you say how you know that the value of the max-width property changes? (I don't believe it does BTW). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with making a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with max-width, you tell the browser what is max-width of the element.
if the max-width of the element is bigger than 500px it will make the height of the element bigger.

with max-width, you set the maximum width and therefore it can be smaller but not bigger than 500px

Answer (score 0):

*Max-width* determines maximum width which an element can have. It means your element can get every width less than your max-width.
You should write *min-width* to specify minimum width that you expect.

```
Min-width:500px;
```

And write *width* for exact value.

Answer (score 0):

Max-width tells that the element cant exceed that point, min-width tells that the element cant be below the value, therefore use min-width if you want your element not to shrink or lower its width